# Bottom navigation with navigation component when fragment load flickering happens

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview, flicker

I am currently using bottom navigation with navigation component, it is working correctly but when we click on navigation item fragment is loading then flickering is happening, flicker is happen even current item selected also. It is happening when fragment is loading. My application screen background is not white when it is white no flickering is displaying i have try all available solutions.

I have change background color of google navigation sample application then also i am able to see the flicker.

If anyone have any solution please post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find solution for my problem i'm having flickering because my background color is black if i change it to white i didn't have any flicker for that i have update theme by adding bellow lines.

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#000000</item>
```

By adding these lines i have avoided the flicker problem.

Answer (score 3):

The flickering happens because of the default crossfade animation that the bottom navigation uses. You can overwrite the animation by creating the following files in the `res\animator` package.

```
nav_default_enter_anim.xml
nav_default_exit_anim.xml
nav_default_pop_enter_anim.xml
nav_default_pop_exit_anim.xml
```

This should be the content of those files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Overwrite the default animation. -->
</set>
```

Comment: This is working, but the directory is res/anim

Answer (score 0):

Use these two lines in your Fragment Container.

`android:layout_height="match_parent" app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nvBottomNavigationMenu"`