# Flickering when navigating fragments in Android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to Android Studio, and I started developing a mobile app with the Bottom Navigation Views Activity template. In one of the fragments (DashboardFragment), I created a button (id = buttonAddBreakfast) that opens a new fragment of the ProductListFragment. This opening fragment has a fragment closure button (id = buttonCloseFragment). I ran into the following problem: after I open this fragment, when I close it and navigate between other fragments, there is a flicker for a split second. Can you tell me how I can fix this?

DashboardFragment:

```
package com.example.calorieapp.ui.dashboard;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.calorieapp.R;
import com.example.calorieapp.databinding.FragmentDashboardBinding;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView homeHorizontalRec;
    private List<HomeHorModel> homeHorModelList;
    private HomeHorAdapter homeHorAdapter;

    private FragmentDashboardBinding binding;
    private TextView currentDateTextView;
    private ImageButton openDatePickerButton;
    private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();



        // Найти кнопку добавления завтрака
        Button buttonAddBreakfast = root.findViewById(R.id.buttonAddBreakfast);

        // Установить слушатель нажатия
        buttonAddBreakfast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Create a new instance of the ProductListFragment
                ProductListFragment productListFragment = new ProductListFragment();

                // Get the FragmentManager
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

                // Start a FragmentTransaction
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                // Replace the current fragment (DashboardFragment) with the new one (ProductListFragment)
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main, productListFragment);

                // Add the transaction to the back stack, so you can return to the previous fragment
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

                // Apply the transaction
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });





        homeHorizontalRec = root.findViewById(R.id.home_hor_rec);

        homeHorModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        homeHorModelList.add(new HomeHorModel(R.drawable.pizza, "Pizza"));
        homeHorModelList.add(new HomeHorModel(R.drawable.hamburger, "Hamburger"));
        homeHorModelList.add(new HomeHorModel(R.drawable.fried_potatoes, "Fries"));
        homeHorModelList.add(new HomeHorModel(R.drawable.ice_cream, "Ice Cream"));
        homeHorModelList.add(new HomeHorModel(R.drawable.sandwich, "Sandwich"));

        homeHorAdapter = new HomeHorAdapter(getActivity(), homeHorModelList);
        homeHorizontalRec.setAdapter(homeHorAdapter);
        homeHorizontalRec.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        homeHorizontalRec.setHasFixedSize(true);
        homeHorizontalRec.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        currentDateTextView = root.findViewById(R.id.currentDateTextView);


        // Установка текущей даты в текстовом поле
        setCurrentDate();

        // Инициализация DatePickerDialog
        initDatePicker();

        binding.layoutForDateToday.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // При нажатии, отобразите DatePicker
            datePickerDialog.show();
        });




        // Предположим, у вас есть значения для белков, жиров и углеводов
        double proteinValue = 140.0; // Пример значения для белков
        double fatValue = 56.0; // Пример значения для жиров
        double carbValue = 240.0; // Пример значения для углеводов

        // Вычислите общую сумму, чтобы распределить прогресс в зависимости от общего значения
        double total = proteinValue + fatValue + carbValue;

        // Вычислите проценты для каждой части прогресс-бара
        int proteinPercentage = (int) ((proteinValue / total) * 100);
        int fatPercentage = (int) ((fatValue / total) * 100);
        int carbPercentage = (int) ((carbValue / total) * 100);

        TextView proteinTextView = root.findViewById(R.id.proteinValue);
        proteinTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.1f г.", proteinValue)); // Вставляем значение белков

        TextView fatTextView = root.findViewById(R.id.fatValue);
        fatTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.1f г.", fatValue)); // Вставляем значение жиров

        TextView carbTextView = root.findViewById(R.id.carbValue);
        carbTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.1f г.", carbValue)); // Вставляем значение углеводов

        // Установите ширину каждой части прогресс-бара
        setProgressBarWidth(binding.proteinProgress, proteinPercentage);
        setProgressBarWidth(binding.fatProgress, fatPercentage);
        setProgressBarWidth(binding.carbProgress, carbPercentage);

        return root;
    }

    private void setCurrentDate() {
        // Получение текущей даты
        Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        // Форматирование и установка текущей даты в текстовом поле
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
        currentDateTextView.setText(formattedDate);
    }

    private void initDatePicker() {
        // Получение текущей даты
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Инициализация DatePickerDialog
        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(requireContext(),
                (view, year1, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) -> {
                    // Обработка выбора новой даты
                    onDateSelected(year1, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                }, year, month, day);

        // Настройка режима отображения DatePicker в виде спиннера
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(true);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
    }

    private void onDateSelected(int year, int month, int day) {
        // Обработка выбора новой даты
        Calendar selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        selectedDate.set(year, month, day);

        // Форматирование и установка текущей даты в текстовом поле
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(selectedDate.getTime());
        currentDateTextView.setText(formattedDate);
    }

    private void setProgressBarWidth(View progressBarPart, int percentage) {
        // Получите LayoutParams для текущего параметра прогресс-бара
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = progressBarPart.getLayoutParams();

        // Установите ширину в процентах от общей ширины прогресс-бара
        layoutParams.width = (int) (getScreenWidth() * (percentage / 100.0));

        // Примените изменения
        progressBarPart.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }



    private int getScreenWidth() {
        // Получите ширину экрана устройства
        return getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    }
}
```

ProductListFragment:

```
package com.example.calorieapp.ui.dashboard;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import com.example.calorieapp.R;

public class ProductListFragment extends Fragment {

    public ProductListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_list, container, false);
        View darkOverlayView = root.findViewById(R.id.darkOverlayView);
        darkOverlayView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  // Показываем затемняющий слой перед длительными операциями
        // Add your code to initialize and display the list of products
        // ...

        // Add a button to close the fragment and go back to DashboardFragment
        @SuppressLint({"MissingInflatedId", "LocalSuppress"}) Button closeButton = root.findViewById(R.id.buttonCloseFragment);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Get the FragmentManager
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

                // Pop the current fragment from the back stack
                fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            }
        });
        darkOverlayView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return root;
    }
}
```

I tried using commitNow() instead of commit(), but it didn't help. I tried to remove the animation of transitions between fragments - it also did not help.

[I have attached a gif so that you can understand what my problem is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxPPh.gif)

Comment: Someone has the same problem. Hope it helps 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62528252/bottom-navigation-with-navigation-component-when-fragment-load-flickering-happen#:~:text=The%20flickering%20happens%20because%20of,in%20the%20res%5Canimator%20package.&text=This%20should%20be%20the%20content%20of%20those%20files.

Comment: Please create a new Android Project and follow the navigation architect in a single MainActivity.